# Power automate : Ignore filters in excel

Tags: power-automate

I have this flow created but now I am facing some issues in managing it considering there are many users of the used excel.

I am reading and iterating the Excel rows, is there a way I can ignore the filters applied by someone in excel? Somehow if filter is applied by anyone, I just get filtered row in flow.

Comment: You could look at using an Office Script to clear the filter before hand. See [How to remove filter in excel online sheet?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-remove-filter-in-excel-online-sheet/td-p/855462)